# настройка python в sublime text 3

Tags: python

Что делать если многое обыскал, ни как не пойму что делать. помогите пожалуйста.

```
[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
[cmd: ['python37', '-i', '-u', 'C:\\layout\\app.py']]
[dir: C:\layout]
[path: C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\Astronaut Pavel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Python37;]
[Finished]
```

создал в tools -> Build system -> New build system:

```
{ 
    "cmd": ["python37", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python" 
}
```

а для проверки использовал:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: В настройках в `"cmd": ["python37", "-i", "-u", "$file"],` замените python37 на python - там должно быть имя файла python.exe, а не имя папки.

Comment: или может еще быть python3 - все зависит от вашей конкретной ситуации.